# $SO(3)$ 5×5 irrep: what does it look like explicitly? (Zee IV.1)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, rotation

BACKGROUND.

So my understanding is this: the $3\times3$ rep of $SO(3)$ are matrices $R$ that rotate a vector $x$, for example:

$$ x \rightarrow Rx =
\left(\begin{matrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&C&S \\ 0&-S&C \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}{x\\y\\z}\end{matrix}\right) ,$$

with $C=\cos\theta$ and $S=\sin\theta$. Instead of acting on vectors $x$, $R$ can act on a 2-rank $3\times 3 $ tensor $t$:

$$ t\rightarrow RtR^{-1},~~
t=\left(\begin{matrix} a&b&c \\ d&e&f \\ g&h&i \end{matrix}\right) .$$

Or we can go from a $3\times3$ rep to a $9\times9$ and $9\times1$ rep:

$$ T \rightarrow (R\otimes R) T$$

with

$$~~(R\otimes R) = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
 1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
 0&C&S&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
 0&-S&C&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&C&0&0&S&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0&C^2&C S&0&C S&S^2\\
 0&0&0&0&-C S&C^2&0&-S^2&C S\\
 0&0&0&-S&0&0&C&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0&-C S&-S^2&0&C^2&C S\\
 0&0&0&0&S^2&-C S&0&-C S&C^2\\
\end{matrix}\right)
,~~T=\left(\begin{matrix} a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i \end{matrix}\right).
$$

Next, this 9 rep decomposes into $1\oplus 3\oplus 5$ so we should be able to block-diagonalize it into 1×1, 3×3 and 5×5 blocks. To do this, Zee looks at the objects being transformed, and groups them into diagonal, asymmetric and traceless symmetric:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix} 1&  0&  0\\ 0&  1&  0\\ 0&  0&  1 \end{matrix}\right)\\
\left(\begin{matrix} 0&  0&  0\\ 0&  0&  1\\ 0& -1&  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 0&  0& -1\\ 0&  0&  0\\ 1&  0&  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 0&  1&  0\\-1&  0&  0\\ 0&  0&  0 \end{matrix}\right)\\
\left(\begin{matrix} 0&  0&  0\\ 0&  0&  1\\ 0&  1&  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 0&  0&  1\\ 0&  0&  0\\ 1&  0&  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 0&  1&  0\\ 1&  0&  0\\ 0&  0&  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 1&  0&  0\\ 0&  1&  0\\ 0&  0& -2 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 1&  0&  0\\ 0& -1&  0\\ 0&  0&  0 \end{matrix}\right)
$$

The same tensors in the 9×1 form:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\  0\\  0\\ 0\\  1\\  0\\ 0\\  0\\  1 \end{matrix}\right)
~~~~~
\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\  0\\  0\\ 0\\  0\\  1\\ 0\\ -1\\  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\  0\\ -1\\ 0\\  0\\  0\\ 1\\  0\\  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\  1\\  0\\-1\\  0\\  0\\ 0\\  0\\  0 \end{matrix}\right)
~~~~~
\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\  0\\  0\\ 0\\  0\\  1\\ 0\\  1\\  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\  0\\  1\\ 0\\  0\\  0\\ 1\\  0\\  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\  1\\  0\\ 1\\  0\\  0\\ 0\\  0\\  0 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\  0\\  0\\ 0\\  1\\  0\\ 0\\  0\\ -2 \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\  0\\  0\\ 0\\ -1\\  0\\ 0\\  0\\  0 \end{matrix}\right)
$$

The vectors above are mutually orthogonal. They provide a complete basis. Normalize them, and make them columns in a matrix $S$. Then I expected the following to be block diagonal (1,3,5):

$$ S^{-1}(R\otimes R)S $$

However, I get a 2-block and a 7-block.

QUESTION:

1) Is something wrong in my reasoning? (I'm newish to group theory.)

2) Is there a standard form for the 5×5 rep? Even if I correctly got a 5-block above, it might be some scrambled, non-standard version.

Comment: There absolutely ***is*** a standard form of the spin-2 , so the 5x5 representation of the rotation matrices. It is easier to consider their logarithm, so, then the linear combination of the three generators $S_x,S_y,S_z$ of the group, given in [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins) explicitly. Lie has convinced the world that is its much easier to work in the Lie algebra than in the Lie group you are considering here. There is a Clebsching similarity transformation to unravel your problem, but is is more conventional to approach it through the Lie algebra...

Comment: Thanks for the Wikipedia link! Now I see the connection.
I still would like to make sure my approach somehow can me made to work... it helps me learn to work things out explicitly.

Comment: It is straightforward, but painful, to do the whole enchilada (*not just* a rotation around the x-axis!), by adapting a spin 1/2 x spin 1 problem I'd given out as [homework prob 4](https://ea6d5eb7-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/ckzachos/Home/qftiiinu2015/QFTiiiProb.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cpMV7Is69h2c1Ym9f4Llhnd_wTFlY6_Uu4F59YbVAElPWTYsqX9vsjkagku8PgoNZrclvky7tPPwslxnAqS8cLsQCocrPj1PN-JxPujxzbSvQa-2ebHKPFUEnbmqCC4ZqehfJSMaLh6R6PDO9a2kVW45FVF1ujHDzRCzHCtj7NZGCCGrvQrcL3XM9bMs6ORcYs5a2lGOy9Vwx8Pjqm_53aXtyvrUYRYpf5Q3vPp_MJSk7Tv3Fo%3D&attredirects=0) five years ago, to your spin 1 x 1 case.

Comment: ... i.e., 3x3 in that language. I could *start* it in algebra space, if you *really* want that, and you could finish it off given the Clebsch matrix for full finite rotations, *all types* of them.

Comment: Great! I'll pour over the homework. And if you do have the energy to start, I'll take what i can get. ;)

Comment: Somewhat [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/464735/two-spin-1-system-and-the-projector-onto-total-spin-2-subspace).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll transcribe the homework problem 4 I refer to in the comments, adapting it to your specific problem, as a hint, since there is no space in serial comments... I have never laid eyes on Zee's text, however, and my discussion below does *not* follow Tony's symmetry driven shortcut.

Working in Lie algebra generator space is easier, in my mind, and SO(3) is so neat, in that you may ignore $j_-$, as its effects follow by hermitean conjugation of $j_+$. Only $[j_0,j_+]= j_+$ and $[j_+, j_-]=j_0$ need checking. For the singlet, triplet, and quintet representations we know from Wikipedia that, respectively, 
$$
 \mathbf{1}: \qquad j_0=0=j_+ , \\
 \mathbf{3}: \qquad j_0=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix} \qquad j_+=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix} , \\
\mathbf{5}: \qquad j_0= \begin{pmatrix}
 2&0&0&0&0\\
  0&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&0&-2\\
 \end{pmatrix}  \qquad j_+= \begin{pmatrix}
 0&\sqrt{2}&0&0&0\\
  0&0&\sqrt{3}&0&0\\ 0&0&0&\sqrt{3}&0\\0&0&0&0&\sqrt{2}\\0&0&0&0&0\\
 \end{pmatrix}  .
$$
The reducible coproduct of generators on $\mathbf{3}\otimes \mathbf{3}$ (necessarily obeying the same Lie algebra!) is
$$
\mathbf{9}:\qquad  \Delta(j_0) =1\!\!1 \otimes  j_0+ j_0\otimes 1\!\! 1= \operatorname {diag} (2,1,0,1,0,-1,0,-1,-2), \qquad \\ \Delta(j_+)=1\!\!1 \otimes  j_+ + j_+ \otimes 1\!\! 1 = \begin{pmatrix}
 0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
 0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\
 0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0\\
 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix} .
$$

It Clebsch-reduces to $\mathbf{1}\oplus \mathbf{3}\oplus \mathbf{5}$ blocks, by a similarity transformation like your *S*, the orthogonal Clebsch matrix. It is very sparse, and its components ($1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 6, \sqrt{2/3},...$) should remind you of the C-G coefficients in standard texts.

You know it is sparse, since it basically operates in the space mixing all three 0 components, and both 1 components, and -1 components of $\Delta (j_0)$. 
That very same matrix will perforce block reduce your rotation matrix, like any rotation matrix, since these should be but exponentials of arbitrary linear combinations of $j_0,j_+,j_-$, all reduced here. In the end, you might do a relabeling transformation of rows and columns for elegance, i.e. have the blocks visibly isolated.

Where is the singlet hiding? Note the null vector of $\Delta (j_0)$ and $\Delta (j_+)$ is the transpose of (0,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,0), so you may project it out to reduce the dimension of the space to 8.

But I will not work out *C* for you...

---

Here is a hint of one of its factors--the one that moves the singlet on the central position, 5, of the 9-vector, and as result the two coproducts looked at have zeros in their 5-th rows and columns and can thereby by ignored: you simply chuck out 5th components of everything and you reduced your problem to an 8×8 one, which you must now reduce to 3×3 and 5×5 blocks. The  partial *C* matrix that achieves that is the orthogonal one
$$
c_0= \begin{pmatrix} 1/\sqrt 2 &1/\sqrt 3&1/\sqrt 6 \\ 0&-1/\sqrt 3&\sqrt{2/3} \\ -1/\sqrt 2&1/\sqrt 3&1/\sqrt 6 \end{pmatrix} 
$$
in the 3,5,7 subspace and with zeros implied in the 1,2,4,6,8,9 entries. 
This moves the null vector found above for the singlet to the central position 5, so $c_0^T \Delta (j_+) c_0$ has vanishing 5th row and column, and, of course, so does $c_0^T \Delta (j_0) c_0$, which was actually left invariant. You may now delete anything connected to the 5th entry, and handle the  8×8 matrices.